# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to launch lutris

Tags: arch-linux, python

I'm having an issue with the latest Lutris version 0.5.16-1. I'm using CachyOS (Arch Linux). Simply put, when I try to launch it, it doesn't start. The console says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lutris", line 58, in <module>
    from lutris.gui.application import Application  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lutris'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install it? On ArchLinux's site, the missing files are supposed to not be missing: https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/lutris/files/ (in particular: `usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lutris/gui/application.py`)

Comment: I installed it like this: sudo pacman -Sy lutris, then I removed it because it didn't work, I tried a few Lutris versions and it doesn't work here either.

Comment: @A.B
I didn't add any file anywhere. I simply installed Lutris once via pacman and it didn't work, then I tried a few others and it still didn't work.

Comment: but (again) what about /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lutris/gui/application.py ?

Comment: @A.B I apologize, I have the file you're asking about in the location you mentioned. I misread it.

Comment: As that was the only easy thing I thought worth checking, I have no more clue about this.

Comment: Okay. Here is the content of the file: https://pastebin.com/CPnHtSTW

Comment: The most common reason for Python not being able to find modules you know to have installed is that you are running a different Python version than the one the module was installed for.  How did you install your Python and what is the output of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version, sys.path)'`?

Comment: @GracefulRestart 
3.11.8 (main, Mar  2 2024, 15:52:43) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801] ['', '/home/golem/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/lib/python311.zip', '/home/golem/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/lib/python3.11', '/home/golem/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/home/golem/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/lib/python3.11/site-packages']

Comment: Looks you're running python within pyenv, rather than using the system-wide python deployment.

Comment: @A.B How do we fix it to make it right?

Comment: Im' not familiar with pyenv. I guess a mix of environment variables, $PATH, .profile and alike maintain the environment. You should know if you installed pyenv. Check this: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv?tab=readme-ov-file#how-it-works . I'm sure somebody else will know.

Comment: Your options would be to use the system Python to utilize the module installed with `pacman` or to install `lutris` into your `pyenv` environment.